# How can I print information from a database (retrieved using java code) into html?

Tags: java, php, html, mysql

I'm doing a web-development project in Java Eclipse IDE. I was wondering if there is a way I can print information from a database and show it on html. In my code below, I have a login function which searches the database table in mySQL for employee_id and password and then validates the login. In that table, there is a column called FirstName, which is the first name of the employee. How can I print the first name of the employee on the home page when they log in? (employeeHome.html)

Validate.java

```
public static boolean userIsAdmin(String employee_id, String password)
    {
        boolean st = false;
        try { 
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/payroll_system", "root", ""); 
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from employee_login where employeeID = ? and pwd = ? and Admin = 1 ");
            ps.setString(1, employee_id);
            ps.setString(2, password);
            ResultSet rs =ps.executeQuery();
             st = rs.next();
```

Login.java

```
if(Validate.userIsNotAdmin(employee_id, password)) { 
            RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher("employeeHome.html"); 
            rs.forward(request, response);
```

employeeHome.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Employee Home Page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="Welcome" method="post">
    <h3>
Employee Home Page
</h3>

    <input type="submit" value="View Personal Information" name="vpi">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="View Expense Claims" name="vec">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="View Payslips" name="vps">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Change Password" name="cp">
     </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: do you know the JSP technology? I think to learn Jsp can be a great start.

Comment: JSP is considered as deprecated. Take a look at JSF:  http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjaam.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use Apache Wicket. We have been using it for 9 years or so and have built large scale enterprise applications for financial institutions. It works well with many technologies and it also has a unit testing framework which we use quite a bit. I highly recommend it. Here's a link. http://wicket.apache.org/

I've never used JSF so I can't vouch for it, but a lot of people use it and it is a Java standard. Either one of these technologies are built for solving the problem that you need to solve in an efficient way.

Now, if you want to do everything yourself and you don't want any frameworks in the way you could write a Java Servlet and output the HTML yourself. Here's a tutorial. There are many on the web. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-first-example

I recommend using a framework. Hopefully my answer will help you make an educated decision for your needs.